# Java to Kotlin converting problem | - or / & - and

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have some problems while converting Java code to Kotlin.
This is example in java :

```
if ((deviceFd.revents & OsConstants.POLLOUT) != 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Write to device");
    writeToDevice(outputStream);
}
```

If we conver this code to Kotlin via Android Studio it produce something like this

```
if (deviceFd.revents and OsConstants.POLLOUT != 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Write to device")
    writeToDevice(outputStream)
}
```

But this code cannot be compiled because of error :

**`operator != cannot be applied to 'Short' and 'Int'`**

So what is the equivalent of Java code to Kotlin ?

Comment: What is the type of `deviceFd.revents`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, it is short

Comment: I don't know if it is correct to use : 
`if (deviceFd.revents and OsConstants.POLLOUT.toShort() != 0.toShort())` ?

It shows no error in this case

Comment: Or : 

`if (deviceFd.revents.toInt() and OsConstants.POLLIN != 0)`

Comment: I would lean towards the `toInt()` approach, though I forget exactly how Kotlin handles this sort of integer conversion.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes but i don't know if it is 100% correct. ANyway i will make some tests

Comment: An int is never equal to a short. kotlin is, in my opinion, unnecessarily strict on types when comparing

Comment: @Zoe, yes i think same, but what is best way to solve this ?

Comment: IIRC the types are always in order, so the first produces a short, but the 0 is an Int. Try replacing the 0 it with `0 as Short`? No idea if that will work or throw a classcastexception though

Comment: @Zoe Kotlin have another way, you say to cast it, but can simply call 0.toShort() , in this way it compile ok but dont know if it is correct to use in this way

Comment: That's converting and not casting though.

Comment: @Zoe thanks, i will try to see what's the difference between two solutions. But, there should be other ways for this . Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, **&** symbol is the bitwise AND operator.

> x & y

If two operands (x and y in this case) have different types, the value of the smaller type is promoted to the larger type implicitly.

> byte, short, char => int => long

- `long & long => long`
- `int & int => int`
- `int & long => long & long => long`
- `(byte|char|short) & int => int & int => int`
- `(byte|char|short) & long => int & long => long & long => long`

In your case,

```
deviceFd.revents (short) & OsConstants.POLLOUT (int)
```

will be promoted.

```
deviceFd.revents (int) & OsConstants.POLLOUT (int)
```

The result is an `int` type.

---

In Kotlin, this is how to do the same as in Java.

Step 1. Because Kotlin **DOES NOT** promote the smaller type to the larger type implicitly, you (as a programmer) must do it explicitly.

```
deviceFd.revents (short) => deviceFd.revents.toInt() (int)
```

Step 2. There is no **&** symbol in Kotlin, so you must use [and](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/and.html) to perform a bitwise AND operation between the two values.

```
deviceFd.revents.toInt() and OsConstants.POLLOUT
```

Put it together.

```
if ((deviceFd.revents.toInt() and OsConstants.POLLOUT) != 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Write to device")
    writeToDevice(outputStream)
}
```

**Update:** Based on the author's comment

```
deviceFd.events |= (short) OsConstants.POLLOUT;
```

Java

```
deviceFd.events (short) | OsConstants.POLLOUT (int)
deviceFd.events (int) | OsConstants.POLLOUT (int)
deviceFd.events = (short)(deviceFd.events (int) | OsConstants.POLLOUT (int))
```

Kotlin equivalent

```
deviceFd.events = (deviceFd.events.toInt() or OsConstants.POLLOUT).toShort()
```

Kotlin

```
deviceFd.events = deviceFd.events or OsConstants.POLLOUT.toShort()
```

> Bitwise Operations is in experimental state, is there any better
> solution?

This is the only official way to use Bitwise Operations in Kotlin. In addition, when
compiling to Java bytecode, they still use Java Bitwise Operations (`| &`) under the hood.

By the way, Bitwise Operations are in an experimental state, but when this feature is finalized, they will be moved
to production state without breaking your current code.